# Recursive blocks in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

We've got our own scripting language that we use. The language is quite simple, but it has one 'exclusive' thing: strings are defined using '[' and ']' (so "test" would be [test]), and these braces can be inside each other:

```
lateinit([concat([test], [blah])])
```

Also, there's **no** escaping character.
How does one parse this block as one string (thus highlighting the `[concat([test], [blah])]` block)?
I currently got the following rule:

```
     { token: 'punctuation.definition.string.begin.vcl',
       regex: '\\[',
       push: 
        [ 
          { token: 'punctuation.definition.string.end.vcl',
            regex: '\\]',
            next: 'pop' },
          { defaultToken: 'string.quoted.other.vcl' } ],
        },
```

But, as you might've guessed, this will stop at brace at the end of test: '**[** concat([test **]**, [blah])]'...

Other examples are:

```
setexpratt(1, [if(comparetext([yes], [no]), msg([test expression]))]);
terminator([confirm([Are you sure you want to exit?])]);
registerfunction([testfunction], 1, 3, [], [msg(concat([Argument 1: ], p(1), [, Argument 2: ], p(2), [, Argument 3: ], p(3)))]);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of nesting them?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It's the syntax; there's no escaping character... The example I gave executes the code given after an object has loaded. So the `concat([test], [blah])` is parsed again, and then ran.

Comment: Any kind of conditionals in that json thing?

Comment: @JavierDiaz 'json thing'? You mean the rules definition as explained here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode#highlighter-rules ? Other than regexes, there's no other conditional (when it enters the push block, it'll continue until it finds the regex `\]` )

Comment: @Diamondo25 I'm not sure how powerful is that regex engine PCRE already supports recursive regex so you may want to give it a try `(\[(?>[^[\]]+|(?1))*\])` it gets recursively everything between `[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add rule for `[` into the inner string state, try

```
this.$rules = { 
    start: [
        { token: 'string.begin.vcl', regex: '\\[', push: "string" }
    ],
    string : [ 
        { token: 'string.begin.vcl', regex: '\\[', push: "string" },
        { token: 'string.end.vcl', regex: '\\]', next: 'pop' },
        { defaultToken: 'string.quoted.other.vcl' },
    ]
};
this.normalizeRules();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job :). I knew it was more advanced than I thought haha