# Ace editor: push and next: 'pop' properties on the highlighting mode rule

Tags: ace-editor

I read "[Creating a new Edit Mode](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode)". However in some modes I can see code that uses `push: 'something'` and `next: 'pop'`, which do not seem to be documented there. Example (code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22766243/39068)):

```
{ token: 'string.begin.vcl', regex: '\\[', push: "string" },
{ token: 'string.end.vcl', regex: '\\]', next: 'pop' },
```

Is there any documentation around `push`/`pop`?
Is `push: "string"` equivalent to the code below?

```
onMatch: function(_, state, stack) {
    stack.unshift("string");
    this.next = "string";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK they are not documented anywhere. push is equivalent to

```
next: function(currentState, stack) {
    if (currentState != "start" || stack.length)
        stack.unshift(this.nextState, currentState);
    return this.nextState;
}
```

and pop

```
next: function(currentState, stack) {
    stack.shift();
    return stack.shift() || "start";
};
```

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.4/lib/ace/mode/text_highlight_rules.js#L112-L121
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.4/lib/ace/mode/text_highlight_rules.js#L164

in your example onMatch would need to `return this.token` in the end.